# Dumpout Process Memory Layout During Loading Time

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ld, dynamic-linking, aslr

I am working on a project where I need to use `LD_PRELOAD` to load some libraries into the memory space.

It's like:

```
 LD_PRELOAD="./libapp.so" ./my_app
```

Due to certain reasons (I am actually working on some binary hacking), I must know **the memory address** (not a symbol) of certain functions (let's say, `foo`) in `libapp.so` and instrument the binary code of `my_app` before execution.

However, due to `ASLR` (Address Space Layout Randomization), each time `libapp.so` would be loaded into different memory address, and I am unable to know the memory address of `foo` before execution.

I am thinking to somehow intercept the loading time, readout the memory address of `libapp.so`, perform some instrumentation on `my_app` with the memory address of `foo`, and then load `my_app` into the memory space.

So here is my question: how to intercept the loading process and acquire the memory address of `libapp.so`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So here is my question: how to intercept the loading process and acquire the memory address of libapp.so?

This can't work: `my_app` is loaded (`mmap`ped into memory) by the kernel *before* the loader starts, and before it had a chance to look at `LD_PRELOAD`.

Your best bet is to either run the application with ASLR disabled (`setarch $whatever -R my_app`), or to arrange `may_app` such that `libapp.so` can dynamically instrument `my_app` once it knows its own load address.